# Function written in jquery is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a page

```
<div id="aar">  
    <div id="stack0" class="stack">stack1</div>
    <div id="stack1" class="stack">stack1</div>
    <div id="stack2" class="stack">stack1</div>
</div>
```

in which the following script run

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".stack").click(function(){
       $("#aar").html($("#aar").html()+'ann');
    });
});
```

The .stack click function run only one time.Why?

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to you replaced the old dom with the new one, and the new one don't have bounded click event handler.

And you could just append the new content by using .append method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".stack").click(function(){
        $("#aar").append(this.id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

User live instead of click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".stack").live('click', function(){
    $("#aar").html($("#aar").html()+$(this).attr("id"));
});
```

});​